# Symfony2 form with entity will always set object to null

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I'm trying to learn symfony2, but now I'm running against a wall by using a form with an entity.
The enitities will be renderd in the form (in a list), but when I try to check which element is selecet the object (here $location) it is empty (null).
I tried the task sample from the manual without any problems, but here I'm lost :(. And the code looks nearly identical ????

Where is my mistake?
Thanks a lot.
Greetings
Martin

My entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity;


/**
 * Location
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Location
{

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Employee", mappedBy="location")
    */

    protected $employees;
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="no", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $no;

    /**
     * @var string
     *`enter code here`
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zip", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $zip;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->employees=new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set street
     *
     * @param string $street
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get street
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * Set no
     *
     * @param string $no
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setNo($no)
    {
        $this->no = $no;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get no
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNo()
    {
        return $this->no;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set zip
     *
     * @param string $zip
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setZip($zip)
    {
        $this->zip = $zip;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zip
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getZip()
    {
        return $this->zip;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add employee
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Employee $employee
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function addEmployee(\AppBundle\Entity\Employee $employee)
    {
        $this->employees[] = $employee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove employee
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Employee $employee
     */
    public function removeEmployee(\AppBundle\Entity\Employee $employee)
    {
        $this->employees->removeElement($employee);
    }

    /**
     * Get employees
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getEmployees()
    {
        return $this->employees;
    }
}
```

My Formclass

```
<?php
/**
 * Description of LocationSelectType
 *
 * @author mwesterm
 */

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Location;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ObjectChoiceList;

class LocationSelectType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {


        $builder->add('name', 'entity', array(
                    'choice_label' => 'Name',
                    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Location',
                    'required' => 'false',
                    'expanded' => 'true'
                ))
                ->add('new', 'submit', array('label' => 'Neu'))
                ->add('edit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Ändern'))
                ->add('delete', 'submit', array('label' => 'Löschen'));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'app_locationSelect';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        /* define your defaults here */
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Location'
        ));
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Controller\MasterData;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\Location;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\LocationSelectType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class EditLocationData extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("editLocations", name="edit_locations")
     */
    public function EditLocationAction(Request $request) {

        $location = new Location();
        $form = $this->createForm(new LocationSelectType(), $location);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            if ($form->get('edit')->isClicked()) {
                return new Response('<html><body>Edit   ID:' . $location->getId() . ' Name;' . $location->getCity());
            }
        }
        return $this->render("masterData/locationEditSelect.html.twig", array(
                    'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that each type you call the function EditLocationAction the variable $location will be re-instantiated.

I think that you are assuming once you hit "submit" the variable $location will be instantiated with whatever you object you selected.

The variable $request is bringing whatever information you selected from the view and processing it through handleRequest to populate the new $form variable.

(More on handleRequest)
http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_handleRequest

For a quick fix (do not know if best practice) maybe I would do a quick dump on the variable $request and find out where in that array is what is you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I find that the problem (or solution) is different. the object is stored in $location->name. So to get the real object which is selected by the user the correct call is $location->getName(). I don't know why, the documentation says something different.